# Can't do more than one activity at a time after switching modems

Tags: dsl-modem

I had to replace the Motorola 2210 DSL modem that I got when I signed up for AT&T DSL Direct a few years ago. The modem kept randomly restarting and it eventually gave out on me. I am assuming overheating was the cause here because it was almost too hot to touch.

In any case, I replaced it with a Netgear DM111PSP. It works fine but I can't do more than one activity at a time with it. If my wife is watching Netflix, there is a noticeable delay/latency when trying to view web sites. It's even worse if I try to play an on-line game while she's streaming; the game is basically unplayable.

The odd thing is, the only other activity I can do while she's streaming is stream another Netflix show myself. There is no delay when doing that, no buffering either. I'm not a networking guy so maybe there is an explanation for it but I find that kind of odd.

I've tried using QoS through my Buffalo N600 wireless router and it doesn't seem to help. With the old Motorola modem, she could be watching Netflix while I play a game and everything worked just fine.

Is there anything I can check or reconfigure possibly on the modem that would account for this? Should I just ditch the Netgear and get another modem instead?

I have the Netgear modem connected to the Buffalo router in a bridged mode. Its the same exact setup as I had with the Motorola and as far as I can tell, it's not the router that is the cause.

Comment: Enabling QoS on both the router and modem (if it has this feature) could cause some problems. And in your situation QoS should be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running your Buffalo router in a bridged mode, try running it in a routed mode so that it "NAT's" all the packets.

Whats probably happening is that your Netgear router is getting confused with the number of routes (ie its routing cache is not big enough), and is having problems.    By using NAT you can translate the source address the router sees, simplifying what the Netgear needs to handle.

Or just chuck it out and get a decent router.